# The first entry of DataTable fills the whole access database

Tags: c#, ms-access

I have read an excel file to a DataTable but only the first row fills the whole MS Access database. I have confirmed that the data in the DataTable and in the Excel file are the same. My code is shown below:

```
using (OleDbConnection myCon = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + outFilePath + ";Extended Properties=dBase IV"))
{
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();

    string line = "001";
    for (int n = 0; n < dt.Rows.Count; ++n)
    {

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dt.Rows[n].Field<string>(0))) break;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO " + FileName +
            "([JNL],[LINE],[TYPE],[DRACC],[CRACC],[EXPDRACC],[EXPCRACC]," +
            "[DOCDATE],[REF],[DRAMT],[CRAMT]) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        string inacc = dt.Rows[n].Field<string>(0);                
        string justNumbers = new String(inacc.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
        string acc = String.Format("{0:##-######-#}", justNumbers);
        string jnl = JNL;
        string Ref = REF;
        string type = TYPE;
        int dramt = 0;
        int cramt = 0;
        if (type == "50") dramt = Convert.ToInt32(100 * dt.Rows[n].Field < double>(2));
        else cramt = Convert.ToInt32(100 * dt.Rows[n].Field < double>(2));

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@JNL", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = jnl;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LINE", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = line;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TYPE", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = type;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DRACC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = justNumbers;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CRACC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = justNumbers;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EXPDRACC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = acc;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EXPCRACC", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = acc;                    
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DOCDATE", OleDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@REF", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Ref;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DRAMT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = dramt;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CRAMT", OleDbType.Integer).Value = cramt;


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = myCon;
        myCon.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCon.Close();
    }
}
```

How to resolve this kind of issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the parameters from your command. You are adding ever more parameters to it. Use

```
cmd.Parameters.Clear();
```

as first line of your `for` statement.

You add the first set of parameters and reuse the same command without clearing them, so you end up with a command that has `n*11` (parameters defined/loop).

The first match in the [collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection(v=vs.110).aspx) is used to substitute your commands params so you get `n` Entries with same data.